# Building an AJAX driven website using Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So my question is around a complete AJAX driven website with a powerful / normal Codeigniter backend.

What I want to do is when a user comes to:

http://domain.com/#/controller/function

The main view is rendered based on the value after the #. I want to route my request based on the value after the # symbol and pretend in Codeigniter that everything is normal, do the processing that it would do and then send the output as a "response" to the AJAX request.

How would one go about making this happen? Any suggestions? Ideas on how to architect the application?

Comment: @gov CodeIgniter is a PHP framework..probably one of the best around. http://codeigniter.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [Sammy](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/) for this: "Sammy is a tiny javascript framework built on top of jQuery. It’s RESTful Evented JavaScript."

Example from the website:

```
$.sammy(function() {

  this.get('#/', function() {
    $('#main').text('Welcome!');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

check out pathjs.
It defines roots based on the #
http://mtrpcic.github.io/pathjs/hashtag_basic.html#/about